# Validate non or max. 1 checkbox is enabled in wicket listview

Tags: java, checkbox, repeater, wicket-6

How can I validate that not more than one checkbox is selected in a listview (repeater)?

I have a Form with a ListView in Wicket with following structure:

line 1 to n: `AjaxCheckBox` and `TextField`

Both elements are connected by `CompoundPropertyModel<SimpleType>`. POJO SimpleType looks like:

```
public class SimpleType {
   private boolean enabled;
   private String value;

   Getter/Setter...
}
```

If more than one checkbox is selected, form should reject any changes. So the user must deselect the selected checkbox first before he can choose another checkbox.
I tried with surrounded `CheckGroup` with `IValidator<Collection<SimpleType>>`, but  I need to change `AjaxCheckBox` to component `Check`. In this case `Check` seems to be not updated with state `enabled` from `CompoundPropertyModel`.

Do I really need a Validator or Visitor for this case? How to implement them?

Comment: Why don't you use a radio button instead?

Comment: I had the same idea but the user should have the choice to unselect the property "enabled". Nothing choosen is a valid option, means all items in list are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since radio is not an option here is a simple solution that should work:

For validation use IFormValidator that visits all AjaxCheckBox-es.

For immediate UI response I'd use plain JS that unchecks the previous checked checkbox. This would fire Wicket Ajax call to unselect it at the server side too.
Once the complete form is submitted the IFormValidator would do its work.

Comment: The additional IFormValidator is what  I was looking for. Works as expected. Thanks martin-g!